# CoreData: How to fetch child objects?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to fetch child objects (NameCD) of the parent object (CountryCD), but I have a bug:
CountriesAPI[2441:78546] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "parent == %&"'

Is my relationship okay and how do I fix this error?

```
 func fetchCountries() -> [CountryCD] {
    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<CountryCD>(entityName: "CountryCD")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parent == %&", "CountryCD")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        let countries = try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return countries
    } catch {
        print("CoreDataService - fetchCountries: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}



import Foundation
import CoreData


extension NameCD {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() ->   NSFetchRequest<NameCD> {
    return NSFetchRequest<NameCD>(entityName: "NameCD")
}

@NSManaged public var common: String?
@NSManaged public var official: String?
@NSManaged public var countryCD: CountryCD?

}

extension NameCD : Identifiable {

}

import Foundation
import CoreData


extension CountryCD {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CountryCD> {
    return NSFetchRequest<CountryCD>(entityName: "CountryCD")
}

@NSManaged public var altSpellings: [String]?
@NSManaged public var area: Double
@NSManaged public var borders: NSObject?
@NSManaged public var callingCodes: [String]?
@NSManaged public var capital: [String]?
@NSManaged public var flag: String?
@NSManaged public var latlng: [Double]?
@NSManaged public var region: String?
@NSManaged public var nameCD: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for nameCD
extension CountryCD {

@objc(addNameCDObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToNameCD(_ value: NameCD)

@objc(removeNameCDObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromNameCD(_ value: NameCD)

@objc(addNameCD:)
@NSManaged public func addToNameCD(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeNameCD:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromNameCD(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension CountryCD : Identifiable {

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Ok I made edit and pasted two new screens. I am not sure about the relationship between CountryCD and NameCD. As you can see there is warning on the left side: abstract entity has no children. Maybe this is main problem?

Comment: You want %@ instead of %& in your predicate but what is parent, I can’t see that relationship or attribute?

Comment: If you have the name you don't need to fetch the parent it will already be connected via the relationship variable

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : You are right. I changed it as you wrote and there is another error: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x6000001bcd20> , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)
But your idea is correct. I need to change something else.

Comment: @loremipsum Ok, but when I want to get the data, there is an error: nameCD = "<relationship fault: 0x60000209ffa0 'nameCD'>";
How to resolve this?

Comment: You are giving bits and pieces but based on your other comment this seems to be an array so you use use nameCD.allObjects so you can access all the objects as an array. Google the core data programming guide, it is a little old but it has a good reference. There is a section on relationships

Comment: @loremipsum There is still an error: the list of object looks like this: <x-coredata://FE307B97-9B92-4600-986F-0E3C07CB63E8/NameCD/p2027>; data: <fault>)]]
I really don't understand this database :/ BTW. Sorry for late answer.

Comment: CoreData is not a database. There is no way to know without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It might just me an issue with that one object. That UUID is an objectID if you only get it with the same object delete it.

Comment: https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-core-data-fault/

Comment: @loremipsum Ok I made the Edit. I hope it will be ok.